# Using a GPIO to unlock an electronic lock

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, electronics

I want to build a safe that can only be opened via an HTTP POST request. In order to do this the safe will contain a Raspberry Pi Zero W that will host a simple server that listens to these requests and uses rpi-gpio.js[1] to unlock an electronic lock[2].

This lock uses a 12V DC 2A power supply as the standby power, but it also needs a 12V signal to unlock electronically. I initially wanted to unlock it directly using one of the 3,3V GPIOs on the Raspi, but the lock would not unlock when setting the pin to 1. I tried several GPIOs, checked that they are functioning correctly, and they are indeed outputting the documented signal. I also tried using the 5V pin on the GPIO (that cannot be controlled) to see if 5V would be enough, but no luck on that as well.

The lock does unlock correctly if I feed the 12V 2A signal from the power supply (the same power supply I'm using to power the lock on standby) into the positive unlock input on the lock's logic board.

Since I can unlock it using the 12V signal from the power supply, I want to use one of the GPIOs on the Raspi as a switch to open/close the circuit. Here's an idea of what I want to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFufk.png (mirror: https://i.postimg.cc/MH2wLh8m/untitled.png)

I was thinking about using a transistor, but I don't really know anything about electronics, so I'm kinda lost here.

How can I do this?

Any insights are appreciated. Thanks for reading.

[1] https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpi-gpio

[2] [https://www.amazon.com/Electric-Electronic-TPEKKA-Fireproof-Doorbell/dp/B074Z55WWG/ref=sr_1_110?dchild=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074Z55WWG)

Comment: Have a look at 12v relays e.g. https://www.hackster.io/paulfp/the-ultimate-raspberry-pi-smart-home-door-lock-3c55a0 or https://www.iotdesignpro.com/projects/iot-based-solenoid-door-lock-using-raspberry-pi-4 - as this is more electronics (for now) I'm voting to close.

Comment: Thanks, just checked your links. Would an IRF520 be suited for this?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the external power supply to the lock a 12V relay switch should work well with GPIO pin. You could then create a python script and include something like this:

```
def (pin):
  global relayState

  if(GPIO.input(buttons[0])==0):
    if(relayState[0]==0):
      print('button 1 pressed, turning on relay 1')
      relayState[0]=1
      relayHandle(0,1)
    else:
      print('button 1 pressed, turning off relay 1')
      relayState[0]=0
      relayHandle(0,0)
```